# Debian Battery Monitoring driver

Tags: debian, lxde, battery

I recently installed Debian Jessie (8) to my Lark Ultimate 7i WIN. I successfully installed all essential things on it, but one thing is still irritating me. I have LXDE installed, and I added "battery monitor" applet to the bottom bar, but it only shows black rectangle. It says 0%, 0:00 until full charge. I installed `upower`, and it says that the battery is 100%. And `acpi -b` says the same as lxde. The driver that the battery is using is `Intel Real Battery Monitor` and the battery is model `SR Real Battery` (from `/sys/class/power_supply/BTBM/`). I have tried adding some lines to lxde autostart, but nothing, that I tried did not work.

Comment: `$ dmesg | grep -i bat`

Comment: `[5.98...] ACPI: Battery Slot [BMBT] (battery present)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the curious ones, this was solved simply by upgrading the kernel (by migrating to debian 9 (stretch) and using backports, using debian sid, or by using Arch Linux). On latest kernels (probably 4.15+, 4.17 for sure), the battery works fine with driver/module `axp288_fuel_gauge`. Really nice piece of software.